# GitHub Jupyter viewer blocking links to Google Colab

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook, href, google-colaboratory

I try to link from Jupyter Notebooks hosted at GitHub to their interactive versions at Google Colab. However, links do not work (GitHub blocks them, one need to copy and paste them or right-click and manually select "open in a new tab").

- Is it an error or some expected behavior?
- Is there a workaround?

Examples: [Gradient descent](https://github.com/stared/thinking-in-tensors-writing-in-pytorch/blob/master/2%20Gradient%20Descent.ipynb) and [Using an ImageNet-pretrained model](https://github.com/stared/thinking-in-tensors-writing-in-pytorch/blob/master/extra/Using%20an%20ImageNet-pretrained%20model.ipynb) from [Thinking in tensors, writing in PyTorch](https://github.com/stared/thinking-in-tensors-writing-in-pytorch).

[image]

What does not work:

```
[![](https://colab.research.google.com/assets/colab-badge.svg)](https://colab.research.google.com/github/stared/thinking-in-tensors-writing-in-pytorch/blob/master/3%20Linear%20regression.ipynb)
```

or

```
<a href="https://colab.research.google.com/github/stared/thinking-in-tensors-writing-in-pytorch/blob/master/3%20Linear%20regression.ipynb">
    <img src="https://colab.research.google.com/assets/colab-badge.svg"/>
</a>
```

Then after clicking (on GitHub; locally there is not problem) there is:

[image]

If I add `<a href="..." target="_blank">...</a>` then clicking does nothing and I see error message (Chrome console):

> Blocked opening 'https://colab.research.google.com/github/stared/thinking-in-tensors-writing-in-pytorch/blob/master/extra/Using%20an%20ImageNet-pretrained%20model.ipynb' in a new window because the request was made in a sandboxed frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set.

Comment: `<a href="https://colab.research.google.com/github/stared/thinking-in-tensors-writing-in-pytorch/blob/master/2%20Gradient%20Descent.ipynb" target="_parent\"><img src="https://colab.research.google.com/assets/colab-badge.svg" alt="Open In Colab"/></a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `target="_parent"` within the link anchor tags, which is what Colab does when it adds such links to notebooks saved on github.